# How to ignore specific columns for calculating softmax attention?

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, deep-learning, pytorch

I am implementing a model which is based on MemoryNetworks. I have triplets data of `(context, query, answer)`. And I want to calculate attention. The attention indicates which sentences in a context should be focused.

To formulate mini-batch, I use zero-paddings to create `context` data. So the following is attention data. And 0 values show a result of embeddings of zero-padded context.
In such a data, I want to apply softmax to indices `0, 1, 2, 3, last`. So the model should ignore zero padding columns.

So how do I realize this? I want to know such a technique when we use zero-padding and attention mechanisms. Although I prefer pytorch, any tools or just description answers will be also appreciated.

```
Before softmax.  torch.bmm(contex, q)
 109.8601
  77.6376
  68.3927
 199.1673
   0.0000
   0.0000
   0.0000
   0.0000
   0.0000
   0.0000
   0.0000
   0.0000
   0.0000
   0.0000
 348.0155
[torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 15 (GPU 0)]

After softmax. F.softmax( torch.bmm(contex, q) )
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
[torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 15 (GPU 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscript your tensor with another tensor in pytorch.

Thus if I have:

```
T = torch.from_numpy(np.arange(10))
```

> 0
>    1
>    2
>    3
>    4
>    5
>    6
>    7
>    8
>    9
>   [torch.LongTensor of size 10]

then

```
T[torch.from_numpy(np.array([0, 3, 7]))]
```

> 0
>    3
>    7
>   [torch.LongTensor of size 3]

So in your case, if you have your `logits` of shape `MBxD`, you can do

```
idx = torch.from_numpy(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, logits.size()[1]-1]))
softmax = F.softmax(logits[:, idx])
```